# How do I find the Jordan canonical form of this 4x4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

A = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 
-2 & 1 & -1 & 1\\ 
2 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I've been given this matrix - I'm supposed to find its Jordan form as well as matrix M such that: $ A = MJM^{-1}$.

So far, what I have is the eigenvalues: 1, 1, 1, -1. 
I have three eigenvectors (which I realize is not enough):

A-1I ~ Gauss Jordan ~ $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$ \qquad \Rightarrow v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$
$ \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

A+1I ~~ $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 3 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$ \qquad \Rightarrow v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -3\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix}$

This is all I've been able to find. I need to either find a fourth vector in order to find matrix M, or a way to find matrix J and then compute M.

Comment: living in the era of supercomputing, use this free tool simply to lean on and understand deeply https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordandecomposition+%7B%7B1%2C-1%2C+0%2C+-1%7D%2C%7B+0%2C+2%2C+0%2C1%7D%2C%7B+-2%2C1%2C+-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B+2%2C+-1%2C2%2C+0%7D%7D in the columns of $S$ are the eigen-vectors

Answer (score 2):

If you had four eigenvectors, you'd be able to diagonalize the matrix. Evidently this matrix is not diagonalizable, but of course it still has a Jordan form. You need to find the "generalized eigenspaces", i.e. the kernels of not just the $(A-\lambda I)$, but also $(A-\lambda I)^n$ for all $n \geq 1$. Since you're only missing one generalized eigenvector here, you'll only need to look at $n=2$ to find your $v_4$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it just for lambda = 1 since that is the only multiple eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the dimension of the generalized eigenspace.

Comment: As you said, I got three vectors for $(A-I)^2$. They are $v_1, e_2$ and $e_4$. Would you mind expanding your answer to how to find which is the one you need?

Comment: @Milly I put something. It is not the case that you can just pick vectors out of the ones you already found.

Comment: @janmarqz in the linked output, the matrix called J is not diagonal

Comment: Wow! the heatwave  is high, sorry! https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/mexico/jalisco/guadalajara-24553131

Answer (score 2):

There is also the matter of consistency. The extra vector, I am going to call it $w,$ has $(A-I)^2 w = 0,$ however $(A-I)w \neq 0.$    Then we take $v = (A-I)w,$ which is automatically an eigenvector. The third and fourth columns of $P$ are $v,w.$ I took column vector $w = (0,0,0,1)^T,$ where the $T$ means transpose. Then $v = (A-I)w = (-1,1,1,-1)^T.$  Next, you take an eigenvector, call it $u,$ that is independent of $v.$ I thought $u = (1,1,-1,-1)^T$ would be nice. Finally, the left hand column is an eigenvector for $-1,$ call it $t= (1,-1,-3,3)^T$

We make the matrix $P = (t,u,v,w) ,$ find $P^{-1},$  and check that $J = P^{-1}AP $ is really in Jordan form

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I definitely see it much more clearly now. About vector $u$, how did you pick it? It's a combination of my $v_1$ and $v_2$, is what I can make out, but is there more to it that I should know?

Comment: Also, how did you know to choose the $w$ that you did out of the three? Clearly the (-1,0,1,0) is out of question, but why not (0,1,0,0)?

Comment: @Milly if I made different choices but followed the rules, both my $P$ and $P^{-1}$ would come out a bit different, but $J = P^{-1}AP$ would come out the same (as long as I used the same ordering of columns). I recommend you do this over, with choice $w = (0,1,0,0)^T$  From your previous question/comment, my $u$ was also a choice; try it with your preference. If you work out the whole problem from start to finish, the method will stay in your mind fairly well